# React Select Always re-render, even when change another state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

React Select Always re-render, even when change another state.

```
...
  const [expense_currency, setExpenseCurrency] = React.useState(expense_claim.expense_currency);
  const [remarks, setRemarks] = React.useState(expense_claim.remarks);
  ...
  ...
  return (
     ...
        <div className="form-group row p-0 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
           <label className="text-nowrap col-form-label col-sm-4">Currency</label>
           <div className="col-sm-8 p-0" title={expense_currency}>
              <Select
                  className="select2"
                  placeholder="Select Currency"
                  isDisabled={false}
                  isClearable={true}
                  value={expense_currency}
                  options={select_currency}
                  onChange={selected => { setExpenseCurrency(selected.value) }}
              />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group row p-0 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
           <label className="text-nowrap col-form-label col-sm-4">
              Remarks
           </label>
           <div className="col-sm-8 p-0">
              <textarea
                 className="form-control"
                 required={true}
                 disabled={false}
                 name="remarks"
                 placeholder=""
                 defaultValue={remarks}
                 onChange={e => setRemarks(e.target.value)}
              ></textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
```

SS from my chrome react profiler

[image]

i have try react-select v2.0.0 to v.2.4.4 all have same result.
can i know how to make it not rerender when i'm update my remarks fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether `Select` is using PureComponent or memo() or something similar. But if it is the props you pass in will break the check every time since you are creating a callback for onChange every render.

To have a consistent callback reference use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback):

```
const onSelectChange = useCallback(selected => setExpenseCurrency(selected.value), [setExpenseCurrency]);
```

And pass it in:

```
onChange={onSelectChange}
```

If `select_currency` is a non-primitive e.g. array or object you will need to ensure that is a consistent reference too. You didn't post that so can't advise.